# Expert opinion needed on a Syllogism Problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Q) Given the statement here. Which of these conclusions logically follow:

Statement: All A are B.

Conclusions:

1. All A are B
2. Some A are B
3. All A being B is a possibility
4. Some A being B is a possibility

The question below was asked in an Indian entrance exam. (for recruiting Clerks)

**The problem with this question is the answers are being disputed by the teachers themselves, and they do not get into a consensus on an answer to this question.**

Your Expert view on this problem will greatly be appreciated.

Sorry for not including the view of some teachers. I am including it below.

***Edit:*** Some teachers argue that the conclusion 3 & 4 do not follow, since all they argue as follows "Since All A are B is true, All A being B is a possibility is false, since if it(3rd statement) were true, that would implicitly mean All A being B can sometimes be false, but it is not so, So it must be false. Hence they Argue that the statement 3 does not follow.(They give a similar reasoning for the "fallacy" of 4th conclusion)

My View is that the statements 4 trivially follow(and 3 by a similar reasoning), since 
$$\text{All A are B }\implies \exists \text{an element in A which is B} \implies \text{The possibility of some A being B}$$

Comment: What is the difference between "All A's are B" and "All A are B"?

Comment: Assuming they mean the same thing. Then I would say 1. follows (since it's the same thing). As for the others, "Some A are B" doesn't follow, since it's possible that nothing are A (in which case all A are B holds vacuously). If it's true it's certainly a possibility, so 3. follows. Also 4 follows, since it's certainly consistent with the first statement that there are some A (and of course these must also be B) some there are some A that are B.

Comment: However since this is not formalized, and (unless we're doing modal logic) it's strange to have 'is a possibility' as part of a formal conclusion, this is probably open to many interpretations and I would be surprised if other people on here disagree with what I said above. I'm also kind of kicking myself for answering for other reasons: you really should have explained your perspective on the question and what the controversy was.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Hi ! Thank you for taking your time to reply to this question. Sorry for missing that. Now I have added my view and some teachers view.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen  "All A's are B" and "All A are B" Sorry that was a typo. Both are exactly same statements

Comment: This idea of 'possibly' implying 'not definitely' seems really unnatural to me. It's funny that the other respondent disagreed with me on 2, not 3/4. Before I went down the 'math hole' I would have certainly agreed "all pink elephants are green" implies that "some pink elephants are green" but years of conditioning have persuaded me that in fact the first statement is true and the second is false (unless pink elephants exist).  Perhaps without this conditioning I wouldn't find the other interpretation of 3/4 unnatural. This shows the importance of formalizing and stating conventions explicitly

Answer (score 1):

All 4 are logical conclusions.
Only the first is equivalent to the original statement.
To understand why the first is the correct correct answer,
let's put some flesh on the statement and consider connotations.

All politicians are human.  That is a fact.

Some politicians are human.  Still a fact but slanders the
profession by connotating only some politicians are human.

It is possible all politicians are human.  Still a fact but
still has a connotation of some inhuman politicians.

It is possible some politicians are human.  This describes
the current situation in US national politics.

Comment: For (1) implying (2), the answer depends on whether they work in a logic that includes existential import; in  modern terms $(\forall x)[A(x) \to B(x)]$ does not imply $(\exists x)[A(x) \land B(x)]$.  It seem we have no way to know what the exam writers intended here.